# Looping over a dictionary of lists and output keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a Python script like the one in the sample below:

```
dictionary = {
'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7', 'value8', 'value9', 'value10'],
'key2': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7', 'value8', 'value9', 'value10']
}

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    i = 0
    for i in range (0, 10):
        print (key, "|", value[i])
        i = i+1
```

### Result expected

I would expect it to print something like the following result:

```
key1|value1
key1|value2
key1|value3
(and so on for all the keys in the input)
```

### Errors I get

1. I see in my iPython notebook the first thing to be printed is a key down in the dictionary I have created, not *key1*
2. At some point the script stops and I see the following error:

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>       189     i = 0
>       190     for i in range (0, 10):
>   --> 191         print (key, "|", value[i])
>       192         i = i+1
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I know I am probably missing something: Thanks to those who will have time to comment!

Comment: What Python version are you using? Previous to Python 3.6 dictionary keys are unordered, so there is no way to guarantee that key1 is going to be the first one to be printed. In the other hand you are iterating up to ten, some value do not have ten elements hence the error.

Comment: Hello @DanielMesejo and thanks for your fast reply. I'm actually using Python 3.5 so I will definitely try with 3.6! About the 2nd feedback, do you know another way to do what I want?

Comment: What is exactly what you want to do? Print the first ten elements of each list? Or print all the elements?

Comment: I want to print the combination of keys and all of their values. Actually, I resolved with your first comment and the answer by @Vishnudev. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping that you have noticed missing `'` quote in the dictionary. Use `in` operator to avoid indexing issues.

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    for val in value:
        print (key, "|", val)
```

Comment: I fixed the missing ' in my sample code since it was not present in my real script. However your answer resolved my question altogether with the comment by @Daniel Mesejo, thanks to both of you!

Comment: @giancampo Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your first problem is that you're missing a ' before value2 in your lists.

Secondly, the `i = 0` and `i = i+1` parts of your code are redundant, since `i` is assigned each time by the for loop. Instead of looping over a range, I would loop over your values list:

```
dictionary = {
    'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7', 'value8', 'value9', 'value10'],
    'key2': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7', 'value8', 'value9', 'value10']
}
for key, values in dictionary.items():
    for value in values:
        print(key, "|", value)
```

Since this will work for an arbitrary length list :)